# Reduce Bluetooth LE transmitting power iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Is it possible to **change/reduce the transmitting power** (== range) of the **Bluetooth LE** module in iOS7 devices (iPhone 5, 5s) programmatically? As far as I know, iPhones have BT class 2, can you set it to class 3?

Perhaps it's possible using BT custom profiles (can you even use them in ios?)

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. There is no public API in Core Bluetooth or any other official frameworks to do that. This is handled exclusively by the OS and there are not even means to read it out inside the device.